# Prevent deletion of folder but let access to everything inside of it

Tags: linux, permissions, directory, chmod, chattr

I know there is the +i flag for files and directories, but i have a deeper Problem.

Is there a way to prevent a folder from being deleted by an User which should be able to create / access / remove files and folders **INSIDE** the delete-protected folder?

The `sudo chattr +i testfolder` flag wont help because then a user can only read files, but not create or delete these.

The `sudo chattr +a testfolder` flag wonth either help because then a user can write and read files, but only append edit files and dont remove them.

I need a solution where a user is able to write, access **and** remove Files but can't delete the root/parent folder.

Answer (score 2):

This is basically what the /tmp folder is for. So just set the permissions that same as /tmp:

```
chmod --reference=/tmp testfolder
```

The `testfolder` should be owned by a different user (e.g. root). The user will be able to `wrx` files and folders under testfolder, but will not be able to remove or modify the testfolder.

For example:

```
[root@host ~]# mkdir /test
[root@host ~]# chmod --reference=/tmp /test
[root@host ~]# ls -ld /test
drwxrwxrwt 2 root root 4096 Feb 15 09:33 /test/
[root@host ~]# su - user
[user@host ~]$ mkdir /test/foo
[user@host ~]$ rm -fr /test
rm: cannot remove `/test': Permission denied
```

As you can see, `user` can create files and dirs under `/test`, but is not allowed to remove it.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but the user is still able to remove the folder ...

Comment: The user must not be the owner of testfolder or its parent.

Comment: Exactly this was the case. Try it yourself

Comment: I updated the answer with an example that show the user can not remove the directory.

Comment: @kevin-vw It depends on permissions of parent folder